# Linear diophantine quasivariety having a unique solution

Tags: nt.number-theory, diophantine-equations

Consider the equation
$$6x+3y+2z=13$$
for $x$, $y$, $z$ nonnegative integers,
with the constraints
$$x=0\implies y=0,$$
$$x=0\implies z=0.$$
The set of solutions $(x,y,z)$ is a kind of [quasivariety](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasivariety)
which in this case is $\{(1,1,2)\}$.

Have multivariate linear diophantine equations like this, having a unique solution, been studied in the literature, or do they easily relate to something that has?

Comment: This is along the lines of a (contrained) [knapsack problem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem).